# Is there a penalty to interrupting training?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have several dwellers who train high SPECIAL attributes, but are needed elsewhere at times (someone has to keep the lights on).

I have noticed that, most of the time (I haven't checked for all scenarios), training times resume back where I left them if the dweller was interrupted or made to work elsewhere; it is as if the system is tracking how much training has been done and getting the dweller back on track.

Is training investment wasted on a dweller if it is interrupted for significant amounts of time for other tasks (including death and exploration)?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dweller training is NOT wasted if you move them before it is finished. You *might* notice some discrepancies between the time left when you move them out and when you move them back in if you have a different number of dwellers in the room, or upgrade the room while they are gone.

For training, the more dwellers in the room, the faster everyone trains, though the gains are only about 10-20% reductions at best. If you have someone with 5 minutes left in training room A along with 5 others, and someone by themselves in training room B with 12 hours left it might be worth switching him,  though that depends to some extent on when you'll next check in.